# SharePoint 2010: How do I use the 'onmouseover' attribute in the ItemStyle.XSL file for the Content Query Webpart?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm currently working in SharePoint 2010, with the Content Query Webpart.
I just want to show a list, but when the user hovers the mouse over the item, I want him/her to see a description. I have tried to put the 'onmouseover' attribute everywhere, but nothing seems to work.

This is my code so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
        <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Description">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Description" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Start">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Start), 1033, 'H:mm')" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="End">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@End), 1033, 'H:mm')" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="Speaker">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Speaker" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="tableStart">
    <xsl:if test="$CurPos = 1">
        <![CDATA[ 
        <table border=1 bgcolor=#CCFFFF>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Start</b></td>
            <td><b>End</b></td>
            <td><b>Title</b></td>
            <td><b>Speaker</b></td>
          </tr>   
        ]]>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="tableEnd">
    <xsl:if test="$CurPos = $Last">
        <![CDATA[ </table> ]]>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:comment>Start of HTML section</xsl:comment> 
<xsl:value-of select="$tableStart" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

<tr>
  <td><b> <xsl:value-of select="$Start"/> </b></td>

  <td><b> <xsl:value-of select="$End"/> </b></td>

  <td style="width:500px"><b> <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/></b></td>

  <td> <xsl:attribute name="onmouseover"> <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/> </xsl:attribute> </td>

  <td><b> <xsl:value-of select="$Speaker"/> </b></td>
</tr>

<xsl:value-of select="$tableEnd" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

Where do I put the 'onmouseover' attribute so that when your mouse hovers over an item, it shows the description?

Thanks in advance.